# SQL statement using WHEN OR IF statement

Tags: sql-server

I am struggling little bit with my SQL query at the moment. I wonder someone can help?

I am trying to pass a string to one of Stored Procedure and based on that I would like to amend the query slightly in the WHERE clause

The param string could be either Alphabets or a Category ID

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[procProductShow]
    @Alphabet varchar(3) = 'ALL' 
AS
    IF @Alphabet =  'ALL' or @Alphabet = 'A' OR @Alphabet = 'B' OR  @Alphabet = 'C' --- UNTIL Z
        SELECT 
            Product.ProdID, 
            Product.ProdImgThumbnailLoc, 
            Product.ProdImgThumbnailAltText

        FROM 
            ProductCategory 
            INNER JOIN Product ON ProductCategory.ProdID = Product.ProdID 
            INNER JOIN Category ON ProductCategory.CatID = Category.CatID 

        WHERE 
            Product.ProdShowOnWeb = 1 AND 
            Category.ShowOnReport = 1 AND               
             (@Alphabet = 'ALL' OR Product.ProdHeading LIKE @Alphabet + '%')    
        ORDER BY Product.ProdHeading

    ELSE
        SELECT 
            Product.ProdID, 
            Product.ProdImgThumbnailLoc, 
            Product.ProdImgThumbnailAltText 

        FROM 
            ProductCategory 
            INNER JOIN Product ON ProductCategory.ProdID = Product.ProdID 
            INNER JOIN Category ON ProductCategory.CatID = Category.CatID               
        WHERE 
            Product.ProdShowOnWeb = 1 AND 
            Category.ShowOnReport = 1 AND               
            Category.CatId = @Alphabet          
        ORDER BY Product.ProdHeading
```

Comment: what is your error/problem specifically?

Comment: mysql or sql server?

Comment: This is Microsoft SQL Server. Try not to tag it with unrelated databases like MySQL.

Comment: Sorry, its MS SQL Server, it was working for Alphabets and All option but not when CatId is supplied

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually simplify this query so that you don't need to do the long IF statement:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[procProductShow]
    @Alphabet varchar(3) = 'ALL' 
AS
    SELECT 
        Product.ProdID, 
        Product.ProdImgThumbnailLoc, 
        Product.ProdImgThumbnailAltText
    FROM 
        ProductCategory 
        INNER JOIN Product ON ProductCategory.ProdID = Product.ProdID 
        INNER JOIN Category ON ProductCategory.CatID = Category.CatID 
    WHERE 
        Product.ProdShowOnWeb = 1 AND 
        Category.ShowOnReport = 1 AND               
         (@Alphabet = 'ALL' 
             OR (@Alphabet LIKE '[A-Z]' AND Product.ProdHeading LIKE @Alphabet + '%') 
             OR Category.CatId = @Alphabet) 
    ORDER BY Product.ProdHeading
```

The `@Alphabet LIKE '[A-Z]'` part of the WHERE condition will perform a regex to check if @Alphabet only contains 'A' through 'Z'

Comment: Thank you so much for your input.    It seems to be working ok for A-Z and All option but when I supply catid, no results.

Comment: SELECT 
        Product.ProdID, 
        Product.ProdImgThumbnailLoc, 
        Product.ProdImgThumbnailAltText
    FROM 
        ProductCategory 
        INNER JOIN Product ON ProductCategory.ProdID = Product.ProdID 
        INNER JOIN Category ON ProductCategory.CatID = Category.CatID 
    WHERE 
        Product.ProdShowOnWeb = 1 AND 
        Category.ShowOnReport = 1 AND               
        Category.CatId = 'PERS'                      --- this return results

Comment: @Alphabet varchar(3) = 'ALL'    - the problem was this line, i have increased the width and its workign ok now !!

Comment: @JohnHill I'm glad that the solution helped :) Be sure to upvote the answer since it have been helpful for you.